# How to display special German characters "ÄÜÖß" in a map?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins, database, encoding

I have a shapefile with names for Regions. These don't seem to contain special characters "Ä", "Ü", "Ö", "ß" but ugly hieroglyphs.

What can I do to display them correctly. If I import the shape as `UTF-8` it doesn't work.

The names are in a dbase table. So is it possible to save a dbase table in `UTF-8` or is there a different way of dealing with it?

Comment: One way that worked for me: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/44016/5901

Comment: Ok, but I can't save modified qgis.bat - "Access is denied"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image]

try opening the dbase-file with libreoffice (or openoffice) and try different encodings, if utf-8 doesnot work try iso-8859-1 and look if the chars öäüß are displayed correctly

Answer (score 9):

In newer versions of QGIS you can right click the layer and select properties. In the first tab there is a section about layer information with the options for data source encoding. You can select UTF-8 there. Sorry for the German screen shot but since the question was about German characters...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your shapefile is most probably in UTF-8, but qgis 1.8.0 has a bug in correct encoding of shapefiles. Until this is solved, you can try this workaround in Windows:

Browse to C:\Programs\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin on Windows XP or C:\Programs (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin on Windows 7. Look for qgis.bat and open it with a suitable editor (I have installed notepad++ for such things). After line 1, insert:

SET SHAPE_ENCODING=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

No I solved the problem: I opened the dbf file in LibreOffice as UTF8, put in the special characters and saved it. That  was it. Very simple!

Comment: sounds like @Kurt solved your problem.  Please consider marking his answer as correct to close this question.

Comment: Yes, I used the same method when facing the problems with destroyed Czech characters - used the same Libreoffice spreadsheet to produce the source CSV for my layer and after saving the layer as SHP, I saved the data from LibreOffice as UTF8 DBF table and simply replaced the DBF in tha shapefile with this one. However, the UTF8 bug is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Excel 2010 and above won't save to DBF formaat any longer so I went the route of adding "SET SHAPE_ENCODING=UTF-8" to the qgis.bat file which worked fine.

I wanted to avoid installing a whole other office suite.

Editing the batch file worked great and now with qGIS the special characters carried right through to .kml and showed up in Google Earth.