# How to read Greek fonts (ISO-8859-7) in shapefile attributes within QGIS 1.8.0?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, encoding, font, greece

I'd like to ask whether there is a way to read greek fonts in a shapefile's  attribute table within QGIS 1.8.0.

Comment: You can find a sample greek shapefile here: http://geodata.gov.gr/geodata/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=16&sobi2Id=21&Itemid= at the SHP button

Comment: ... and the GML from the linkbutton next to it works in QGIS without any complaints. AAARGH!!!!

Comment: I'd like to tahnk everyone for their help. I tried most of the solutions provided, expect for the .cpg one which I'll try in my laptop, some of them worked. For INSPIRE datasets, like the ones used from the geodata.gov.gr portal, it works when you select either UTF8 or ISO-8859-7 when opening the shapefile in QGIS. The problem lies with shapefiles produced without specifying the relevant encoding. Nevertheless it seems I can use most of my dataset, maybe it'll be easier in the next QGIS version.

Comment: Please do give the `.cpg` method a try, since it essentially declares the shapefile's encoding - useful if the shapefile was produced without specifying a correct encoding.

Answer (score 3):

You might try creating a file with the same base name as the shapefile but with a `.cpg` extension, containing a single line of text identifying the encoding, be it `UTF-8` or something else. I am not sure if this will resolve the problem with QGIS, but I have had some success with this method to force multi-byte characters in attribute data to be interpreted correctly (typically in situations where attribute data was written in an encoding incompatible with the code page given in the [DBF file header's LDID field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4162464/339879)).

See http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21106 for more info on `.cpg` files.

---

**Update 1:** Just to illustrate that QGIS *does* respond to the presence of `.cpg` files, here is an attribute table screenshot of two identical test shapefiles. The only difference is that attrb has an `attrb.cpg` file declaring `UTF-8`. In this case, the `Unicode test` characters are rendered correctly.

[image: Unicode attribute values, with and without UTF-8 .cpg file]

Both shapefiles have `87` as the value of the Language Driver ID (LDID) byte in the DBF header, indicating [ISO-8859-1 encoding](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5911). Thus, at least in this case, providing a `.cpg` allows the user to override the internally-declared encoding without actually modifying or re-saving the DBF file.

I do not have a shapefile containing Greek characters to test, but you might try declaring `8859-7` (ISO) or `1253` (ANSI) in place of `UTF-8` in the `.cpg` file.

---

**Update 2:** I downloaded a sample shapefile from [the page](http://geodata.gov.gr/geodata/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=16&sobi2Id=21&Itemid=) Andre suggested (thanks!). As you can see, by default the fields containing Greek text do appeared garbled:

[image: Greek shapefile with default encoding]

I then created a file named `nomoi_okxe.cpg` in the same directory as the shapefile, containing the text `1253` (the [Windows code page number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1253) for Greek). I then reopened the shapefile in QGIS:

[image: Greek shapefile with Greek code page specified]

That looks Greek to me!

ZISIS, is this sample shapefile representative of the files you need to work with?

---

**Update 3:** The examples above were based on QGIS 1.8.0 on Mac OS X 10.8.2. I have also tested this method with QGIS 1.7.5 on Linux Mint 14:

[image: Screenshot of sample Greek shapefile with cpg file open in qgis on linux]

Comment: Unfortunately QGIS does not react on any .cpg file.

Comment: On the contrary, QGIS 1.8 does recognize `.cpg` files (I've edited my answer with an example) - but since I don't have a Greek shapefile to test, I concede that it may not be any help in ZISIS' case.

Comment: You can find a sample greek shapefile here: http://geodata.gov.gr/geodata/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=16&sobi2Id=21&Itemid= at the SHP button. I did not suceed with the cpg file...

Comment: Thanks for suggesting some sample data! I've updated my answer again to give a specific solution for that example.

Comment: Yes I can confirm the correct encoding of the Greek names. They appear correctly

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work here on Windows 7. Attibute table looks the same, with .cpg file or without. On what operating system did you run the test?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is specific to Windows; I've tested this method with QGIS 1.8.0 on Mac OS X 10.8.2 as well as QGIS 1.7.5 on Linux Mint 14.

Comment: Yes, looks like that. The data always comes here with ISO-8859-1 characters. We have to use Master or wait for the next stable release. By the way, QGIS 1.7.5 is ok because the error-producing GDAL change came with Qgis 1.8.0/GDAL 1.9.1

Comment: @anoved: Thanks a lot! This works with Vietnamese on Ubuntu 12.04, Qgis 1.8.0.

Comment: @CaoMinhTu Great! Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION A** for utf-8 encoded shapefiles

Supposed you are working on Windows, look for qgis.bat in bin directory, and open it with a text editor.
after the first line, insert

```
SET SHAPE_ENCODING=UTF-8
```

and save.
Qgis 1.8.0 has some problems with encoding, using your computers default font instead of the one you specify. It is fixed in Qgis Master (1.9.0) by now, which you can install with osgeo4w setup.

---

**SOLUTION B** for ISO-8859-7 encoded shapefiles

We had a similar issue lately on the mailing list:

> http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2012-November/020021.html

It works on the cited shapefile only with Qgis Master (1.9.0):

In Settings -> Options -> General, there is a checkbox

```
[ ] Ignore shapefile encoding
```

Uncheck it.

Then open the shapefile in QGIS with ISO-8859-7.

With this option shapefile encoding is done the same way as in Qgis
1.7.4, that is leaving it to QGIS and not GDAL.

If you want to work on with QGIS Lisboa, save the shapefile as `UTF-8` and proceed with Solution A, until the next stable version of QGIS is released.

---

**SOLUTION C**

create a file named `< filename >.cpg` and `1253` as content in the same folder as the shapefile.

convert the shapefile with ogr2ogr:

> ogr2ogr -a_srs EPSG:2100 -f GML nomoi_utf.gml nomoi_okxe.shp
>
> ogr2ogr --config SHAPE_ENCODING "UTF-8" -a_srs EPSG:2100 nomoi_utf.shp nomoi_utf.gml

This allows GDAL to encode ISO-8859-7 on reading, and writes UTF-8. Unfortunately, writing to shp in one step does not work the same way. You can use the GML or the utf.shapefile with Solution A.

Comment: ISO-8859-7 is the root of all evils. Windows still saves in that encoding by default

Comment: ISO-8859-7 is the standard encoding for Greek alphabet support. You can't blame Greek authorities to use that. And it depends on your locale settings what Windows uses apart from utf-8.

Comment: I don't blame them. Although (trust me on this!) the world would be a better place is everyone used the same encoding routines. You can't imagine how many localized char sets, are out there, and how much **guess work** it needs to get it right.  

For example, if you don't know about the magic number 8859-7 , you'll only see gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible if you open the layer preferences, to to General and set the encoding to UTF-8.

Edit: Use OpenOffice to open the dbf, set the encoding to UTF-8 and then hit save. You may need to add and delete a letter to get the save-option.

Comment: Thanx, I tried it but doesn't work. There's also a 'greek' option but doesn't seem to work either. It should be possible but...

Comment: Try to save the shape file as a new one and set the encoding from the start to UTF...

Comment: what kind of encoding does the corresponding dbf- file have. is it utf-8 too?

Comment: Thanx again, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Kurt, how do I check this?

Comment: Managed to read the dbf in Openofiice-Calc in ISO-8859-7 but stil doesn't work.

Comment: You have OOO.. great! Set the encoding to UTF-8 when opening and then save. Then you should be able to use greek letters.  It worked for me just now.

Comment: Thanx, but still can't make it to work. I'll try again soon.

Comment: take a look here. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31885/qgis-how-to-display-special-characters-german-auoss-in-a-map

Comment: utf-8  **is not** is not a general encoding method which covers ISO-8859-7 in it. The characters must be saved in utf-8 from the beginning, or convert them from one base to another.

Comment: Thank you @Kurt, this was the right direction for some Mapinfo vector data with lots of Greek Fields/Strings.