# Does QGIS support internationalization?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, unicode, internationalization

Does QGIS support multiple languages? I have some shapefile with
Arabic names in its attributes, and they appear as: `????`

If I want to see the names in Arabic, do I need to purchase multi-language supporting GIS software or is there any other option?

I am using QGIS 1.8.0.

Answer (score 3):

did you try to use a proper encoding for the shapefile? I suggest you try arabic encoding or utf[image]

Answer (score 3):

Basically, QGIS supports internationalization, but QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa has some problems with correct encoding of shapefiles. There are some workarounds given here:

[How to read Greek fonts (ISO-8859-7) in shapefile attributes within QGIS 1.8.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44009/how-to-read-greek-fonts-iso-8859-7-in-shapefile-attributes-within-qgis-1-8-0)

which are a bit Operating-system-dependent.

The matter was fixed in QGIS Master, but currently the bugfixing for the upcoming QGIS 2.0 may lead to a unstable QGIS Master version.

So you might better wait until QGIS 2.0 is published.

EDIT: This only affects shapefiles, other data sources should work correct.