# Encoding Greek alphabet with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, encoding, internationalization, greece

I have a big type of Greek shapefiles, but a lot of time when I show the attribute table I see ?.????????? .

How can I encode them?

Is there any way to make ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop encode them automatically?

Comment: Do you know what text encoding the shapefiles are using?

Comment: If you've received them from someone, ask to provide them as fcs in personal database. Work with Chinesse for me...

Comment: No unfortunately.! But I think I need a way to encode them to UTF - 8. There was a common case with QGIS at this  article:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44009/how-to-read-greek-fonts-iso-8859-7-in-shapefile-attributes-within-qgis-1-8-0/108543#108543

Comment: And most of the I take from Geodata.gov. It's a site which provide a lot of shapefiles for greek.

Comment: Asker appears to have left the site.