# Several letters missing in QGIS 3.0.3

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, encoding

My QGIS cannot display several letters, like for example Ž, Đ, š.....
Other programs on my PC do recognize these letters/fonts. 
What can I do?

Comment: In what context? Labelling? Layer names? Text on map compositions? What font is it using?

Comment: Just in an attribute table. It si using Qt default: MS Shell Dlg2...

Comment: Can't replicate that on Linux, sorry. Can you try any other Qt applications?

Comment: I can type it into an attribute table, but it doesn't save it apparently...

Comment: Ah wait... the problem arises when I import data as a delimited text layer from excel. In excel the letters are displayed correctly, but when I import them into QGIS they are replaced by a black square with a question mark: �

Comment: When adding the delimited text layer, does selecting UTF-8 encoding work?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. It also occurs when saving a SHP files (with correctly displaying letters) as CSV and opening it in excel. The letters are replaced in excel with different letters.

Comment: This comes down to encoding issues. Please check related threads such as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44009/how-to-read-greek-fonts-iso-8859-7-in-shapefile-attributes-within-qgis-1-8-0

Comment: Thanks a lot! No clue though why my question has been considered off topic, since it is about how QGIS funtions and how it works properly. I'm sure more people face this problem and have no clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up the right encoding in the layer properties. It is not obvious which is the right one. If you are on a windows machine, it will be probably `system`, but it is never granted.

Below the screenshot of the tab where you need to select the `Data source encoding` of your layer.

[image]