# How to fix encoding problems with Turkish characters?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read Greek fonts (ISO-8859-7) in shapefile attributes within QGIS 1.8.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44009/how-to-read-greek-fonts-iso-8859-7-in-shapefile-attributes-within-qgis-1-8-0)

My shapefile contains turkish (latin) letters. (see: http://www.5goldig.de/Tuerkische_Tastatur/Tuerkisch-Buchstaben.html)
The encoding of the shapefile is UTF-8 and I also tried ISO-8859 and several others but the letters are still like that:

ApÄ±Åkar GeÃ§it -> Apişkar Geçit

Is it because of the encoding or is there a other reason?

Comment: Do you also have a .cpg alongside? I can't find definite info, so my wild guess here is that the shapefile format does not support unicode by default and the characters got corrupted while saving.

Comment: Repeated question? Please, take a look at "How to read Greek fonts (ISO-8859-7) in shapefile attributes within QGIS 1.8.0?" (http://goo.gl/qqhnK).

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31885/qgis-how-to-display-special-characters-german-auoss-in-a-map

Answer (score 0):

Open the DBF file in LibreOffice Calc or OpenOffice Calc, provide the encoding (UTF-8) and save it from there.

Comment: Some people has reported that his solution does not work.