# Open Arabic Shapefile in Qgis

Tags: qgis, encoding, internationalization, arabic

I have a shape-file all it's fields are in Arabic. When I opens it in qgis 2.0 all the data is replaced by "?".
I changed the encoding to Arabic or UTF-8 but with the same result.
How can I Open an Arabic Shapefile in Qgis.

Comment: If you can share a small part of the shapefile somebody could do a double check.

Comment: Do these answers help you? See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31885/qgis-how-to-display-special-characters-german-auoss-in-a-map) for how to determine the codepage and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44009/how-to-read-greek-fonts-iso-8859-7-in-shapefile-attributes-within-qgis-1-8-0/44016#44016) for how to define this.

Comment: A sample shapefile:https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ygqcyuiaghe3d1/JStreets.rar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be able to see the Arabic names you may proceed like this:

1) Go to `Layer > Add Vector Layer`

2) Choose the corect Encoding for your layer (`Windows-1256`, otherwise you'll see artifacts):

[image]

3) Just label your streets with `Arabicstre`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Answer: It works for me. I used ISO-8859-6 for Arabic encoding. It even works with a few different fonts. Just one "?" is left over (See picture).

Comment: Maybe the problem is your operating system? Try to install the support for Arabic encoding on Ubuntu or other Distro. If you are on Windows XP or older it might be difficult to get that to work correctly. What version of QGIS are you using and what operating system? Another problem might be missing fonts?

**Edit:**
Using Windows-1256 encoding also works better on Ubuntu for this shapefile. The question mark disappears. Probably the file was created on a Windows machine?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For showing "Farsi (persian)" texts in QGIS:
1) Go to Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer

2) Choose "UTF-8" Encoding for your layer