# How to replace characters to eliminate encoding errors?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, encoding

Working with Qgis, I have a table representing streets. Attributes inlude street name, length, pavement and some others. Unfortunately, all names with ä or ö or ü display 'odd characters' like Ã1/4. When trying to replace these odd characters with real German ones, ALL streets in my list end up having the same name, instead of only replacing these odd characters. How can I replace only certain characters?

Comment: Hi @Jolanda, welcome to GIS SE. First it would be beneficial if you edit your question to include the method you used to replace the "odd character" with the German letters. Second, you might want to reload you shapefile using a different encoding that knows how to read German letters. See this [thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31885/qgis-how-to-display-special-characters-german-%C3%84%C3%9C%C3%96%C3%9F-in-a-map)

Answer (score 1):

To change the strange letters, rightlick on the layer in the table of content, -> Properties, General tab. There you find the `Data source encoding` combo box.

Depending on the source of your data, `utf-8`, `System` or some `windows` codepage will bring you the correct display of the data.

Comment: Just to mention that the thread brought in the comment above suggests: `iso-8859-1`