# Using linguistic phonetic alphabet in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, encoding, internationalization

I want to know if there is a way to use the International Phonetic Alphabet in QGIS?

I am working with a group of linguistics that want to map dialectic varibility in a language (Nahuatl) and I am not able to see the specific characters of a word, usually they appear as interrogations characters.

I tried loading the data in UTF-8 and system.

I am working with windows 10 64 bits in Spanish.

Comment: I have had success in using `UTF-16` for various dialects, perhaps try this?

Comment: Where is the data with the text coming from? Shapefiles? Any chance you can supply us a test dataset so we can have a play? Maybe you just don't have an IPA font on your system?

Comment: my information comes in ashp file, and you are wright i do not think i have an IPA font installed. Which one shoud I use under windows?

Comment: try [this page](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/content/ipa-fonts#winfonts), suggests which fonts have the IPA unicode block.

Comment: I already downloaded and installed doulos sil and charis sil fonts. Both were recomended by the linguist that I am working with. Nevertheless when I load my shape file usin either utf-8 or system I continue with some interrogation characters. I tried to label the communities with a field containing text in phonetic alphabet, changing the font (doulos or charis) and i is the same, som interrogation chatacters. I tried to load in UTF-16 but all my onformation went from spanish to chinese or japanese characters. I wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: UTF8 and Windows can be quite complicated, because of Windows' default encoding. Have you tried to add a `*.cpg` to the shp? Alternatively have you tried to open the file in Linux? I also found a comment somewhere, that Ubuntu can destroy the encoding when saving with default encoding (can't find that one right now). Have you tried [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31889/8673) approach? Have you tried recreating the layer with the right encoding? Could https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapefile_encoding_fixer/ be a solution?

Comment: Found the comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/15914/8673 (I had the situation that Ubuntu somehow destroyed my encoding, then I had to recreate the shape from a backup) 
the next answer is also worth a shot http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/15915/8673