# How to check the encoding in the .dbf files?

Tags: qgis, postgis, dbf, encoding

I am having difficulties when I try to load a shapefile into my database, the is because I do not know the encoding of the dbf portion of the shapefile.
The attribute tables are in Spanish, I have tried `UTF8` and `LATIN1/ISO-8859-1`.

How can I check the encoding of the dbf file? I do not want to waste anymore time trying all the encodings.

The database is Postgres 9.4.4 with Postgis 2.2.1, I use Qgis 2.10.1 to visualize the data before loading it to the database.

Looks like the files were made in a mac, not sure though.

Comment: dBase predated ISO encoding by many, many moons, so this is exclusively an application-specific issue.  Please **edit** the question to specify what GIS software you are using.  You should also specify the database software in use, since some of them predate encoding schemes as well.

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: @klewis there is no error message, the letters with accents just appear with question mark

Comment: see this post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/which-character-encoding-is-used-by-the-dbf-file-in-shapefiles, it would seem latin should work if you are using latin characters, http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm

Comment: Have you tried with 'windows-1252'. I've come across some shapefiles with such encoding.

Comment: @gcarrillo no, still the same :/

Comment: Have you use 'System'? :D

Comment: From your post it's not clear when exactly you see the question marks - with the shape in QGIS (as label or attribute table?) or in the database (pgadmin, command line, again QGIS?). Have you tried fixing the encoding with https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapefile_encoding_fixer/ ? Have you tried this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31889/8673 ? Also take a look at the comments of this answer, maybe creating on mac was some issue http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/15914/8673

Comment: @bennos the encoding fixer did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When having enconding issues with a Shapefile you can try the QGIS Plugin [Shapefile Encoding Fixer](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapefile_encoding_fixer/).

Other helpful questions are:

- [Which character encoding is used by the DBF file in shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3529/8673) as mentioned by @If you do not know- just GIS
- [How to encode shapefiles from LATIN1 to UTF-8?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/15912/8673)
- [How to display special characters German “ÄÜÖß” in a map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/31885/8673)